# Using Service in Express Router

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, inversion-of-control, express-router

I am pretty new in the NodeJS but I would like to learn something new. I came from .NET fancy dependency injection, inversion of controll, microservice shiny world so I am trying write some service in TypeScript based on my previous experiences.
I am using express and express router to create some api. I have some methods in router which handles api calls and I want to use some kind of service object for data retrieving and manipulation.
I inject the service into the router using constructor injection but if I want to use my service it throws an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'layoutService' of undefined

I understood that the methods were called withouth context so I added `.bind(this)` to the each method regsitration and it works, but I dont know if it is the best way how to do it.

Does anyone have a better idea?

**simplified server.ts**

```
import express, { Router } from "express";

// inversion of controll
import container from "./ioc";
import { TYPE } from "./constants";

import IMyService from "./abstract/IMyService";

// import routers
import MyRouter from "./api/MyRouter";

app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const router: Router = express.Router();
const myRouter: MyRouter = new MyRouter(container.get<IMyService>(TYPE.IMyService));

app.use("/", router);
app.use("/api/v1/layouts", layoutRouter.router);
```

**MyRouter.ts**

```
import IMyService from "./abstract/IMyService";
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";
import { inject } from "inversify";
import { TYPE } from "../constants";

export default class MyRouter {
    public readonly router: Router;
    private readonly myService: IMyService;

    constructor(
        @inject(TYPE.IMyService) myService: IMyService
    ) {
        this.myService = myService;
        this.router = Router();
        this.routes();
    }

    public GetAll(req: Request, res: Response): void {
        this.myService.getAll()
            .then(data => {
                const status: number = res.statusCode;

                res.json({ status, data });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                const status: number = res.statusCode;

                res.json({ status, err });
            });
    }   

    public GetOne(req: Request, res: Response): void {
        const id: string = req.params.id;

        this.myService.getOne(new ObjectID(id))
            .then(data => {
                const status: number = res.statusCode;

                res.json({ status, data });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                const status: number = res.statusCode;

                res.json({ status, err });
            });
    }

    routes(): void {
        this.router
            .get("/", this.GetAll)
            .get("/:id", this.GetOne);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your function with the arrow syntax (ES6), it will "bind" the context to it automatically and you won't need to `bind` them. But it will depends on your use case (ou might need to bind a different context)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried wrote the funkcionality like this.router.get("/", (req, res) => { ... }).get("/:id", (req, res) => { ... })... and  it realy worked, but to me it was not so readable because all funkcionality was chained to one long command. So I changed that a bit to somethink like this this.router.get("/", (req, res) => this.GetAll(req, res)).get("/:id", (req, res) => this.GetOne(req, res))... and it still works nice and the readability is fine for me now. So thank you for your help.